# vehicle of and means of

Tags: meaning

> Stoic thought is not intended, in this instance, to replace the
>   specific religion that forms the vehicle of morning reflection, but
>   rather as a means of enabling a purer reflection on the issues of
>   faith which may affect the rest of your day. This process of
>   reflection may commence after clearing the mind of unnecessary emotion
>   and distracting passions.
>
> [Dale Kingsley, Stoicism a beginners guide to the history and
>   philosophy of stoicism]

"vehicle of" = "means of"?

"the rest of your day"? I don't know the meaning of "day" here. Does it mean "life" or "time" or just "a period of 24 hours"?

Could you help me please!?

Answer (score 2):

Passages of this kind, often written in elaborate, metaphor-heavy prose, are typical of philosophical tracts and open to interpretation.

In this instance *vehicle of* could easily be replaced by *means of*, as you suggest.

Whether *day* refers to *each day, any day, every day* is up to the reader to understand. If the writer had said **affect the rest of your life** it would mean much the same thing.

In short, when it comes to interpreting poetic or philosophical prose, it's a matter of opinion (while allowing informed opinions to be rather more valuable than uninformed).

Comment: Indeed, I'd gloss "the rest of your day" as "when you're actually doing things (rather than philosophizing)".